# Quickly changing Bottom Navigation app crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, bottomnavigationview

I have Bottom Navigation with fragment and Retrofit for api call

I call `loadFragment` for switching the fragments as below

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is my app crashes if i start clicking randomly and change fragment quickly, when i check logcat it shows NPE while setting some data.

My Fragment consist of following methods

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    context = getActivity();
    callCategoryAPI();
    return view;
}
```

`callCategory()` is api retrofit call in separate controller class and brings back response via `interface` and then set data.

So what i suspect is my API returns response (as its asynchronous) but views are not available as user has changes the fragment (quickly) so views are null.

I already tried `setuserVisibleHint` also tried block click for 1200ms and also checked is my fragment view created, How to stop this crash? and make retrofit call Lifecycle dependent?

**Logcat**

> at com.example.CurrentFragment$1.onApiSuccess(CurrentFragment.java:82)
>          at com.example.services.current_statement.CurrentStatementController$2.onResponse(CurrentStatementController.java:91)
>          at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6606)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>
> --
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>          at com.example.fragment.statements.CurrentFragment$1.onApiSuccess(CurrentFragment.java:82)
>          at com.example.services.current_statement.CurrentStatementController$2.onResponse(CurrentStatementController.java:91)
>          at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6606)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

Comment: Do you really want to shift your fragments quickly?

Comment: I dont want to, but its a bug which i need to resolve before releasing the app ASAP

Comment: please show us the full crash log

Comment: You mean to say that if user quickly shifts the fragment then the app will crash. Right. That's the reason you want to fix it..

Comment: exactly @UmangBurman

Comment: I suggest you block the entire activity when you click on an item in Bottom Navigation as I've also done it in my app. You can block it by using a progress dialog in fragment.

Comment: added logcat, i also tried to disable click for 1200ms but that also dint helped me and not a good solution

Comment: yuj, in onCreateView() add a progress bar visibility as true, then user will not be able to click any item in the navigation, when all the data is visible then hide progress bar..

Comment: I already have that in my retrofit `controller` class before `call.enque`  my api call

Comment: Can you show your retrofit controller class pls

Comment: I cant `controller` contains lot of sensitive code

Comment: Okay, I'll post a pic of what I've done in my app to avoid such issues..

Answer (score 3):

set in your fragment

```
 if(activity != null && isAdded) {

  // perform your task

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in fragment

```
if(activity != null && isAdded){

 Perform your operation

}
```

Answer (score 1):

set in your fragment

```
 if(getActivity() != null && isAdded) {

 //do your operation

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

You would like to set text to a textview which is null. You should check at first that your textview is not null like this:

```
if (textview != null){
    textview.setText("mytext");
}
```

Comment: In this case, he has to add it for so many views.. I don't recommend like this.. IMO

Comment: its not just the TextView i am setting various data after that i cant add 100's of check right?

Comment: The question is why do you get NPE. From your crash log its clearly see why is occurring the NPE...

Answer (score 0):

Use this library below to block the activity until the network operation is finished.

[Spot Dialog](https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog)

This is what I used for my app in the image which I showed you earliar.

Comment: As i already said i have `ProgressDialog` in every API call but when i try to click fast the fragment gets replaced and i get NPE

Comment: Have you used inbuilt ProgressDialog or any library?

Comment: Android default `ProgressDialog`

Comment: Don't use that as it will be limited to a it's view and also doesn't look good. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but i hope i can help other developer as well , for i have encountered this problem too. just use `isAdded()` in your condition at `onResponse` callback inside the if-else

ex: inside your `onResponse` callback :

```
if (isAdded()){
  // success response
} else {
  if(isAdded()){
    // error response
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Timmy. There's something wrong with your code, the `else` is the same as the `if` condition, which would never get executed. Maybe you meant to use just else without an if inside?

Comment: Hi, I'm newbie in android but from what i understood, is that in else if you have code there for ex. Toast, Toast will get nullpointer exception because of click spamming the navigation button calling multiple fragment and immediately destroyed, now inside else you have check again if the fragment isAdded to make sure you dont get nullpointer exception. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

code is for kotlin in android:

`TextView?.text`

here ? mean not null

use it like shows as above

Answer (score 0):

If you change navigation drawer menu item quickly, current fragment will replace by new one too. Android can remove any ongoing calculation that is running in main thread. But if any heavy task like background network response result or handler delayed task that has a reference of fragment can find null because fragment has already detach or replace by new one.

So you just have to check that, your desire fragment is still added in activity or not before process response data that has come lately.

```
    if(frag.isAdded()){
        //lets process your delayed response data
    }
```